# Text centers in the cells and leaning text

Tags: rotating, arrays

Please I would like to make a table as this one but I have some problem to make leaning a text and centered in the cells.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{array,caption,color}
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,multirow}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering\tiny
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{|rp{1 pt}|l|l|p{3cm}|l|}
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Variable}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Description}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Modalité}} \\
    \cline{5-6}    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{Unité ou codage} & \textbf{Nbre} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Les facteurs}\end{sideways}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{démographique}\end{sideways}}} & Sex   & Sexe  & 1 = Masculin; 2=Féminin & 2 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Agemer & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Âge de la mère à la naissance  } & 1 = Moins de 20 ans \par
    2 = 20-34 ans \par
    3 = 35 et plus & 3 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Gemeli & Gémellité & 1 = Singleton \par
    2 = Jumeaux \par
    3 = Triplé & 3 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Morta &     Mortalité des enfants & 1= Décédé av. 5 ans ; 2 = Vivant ap. 5ans & 2 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{5}[10]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Facteurs Socio-économique}\end{sideways}}} & Milresi & Milieu de résidence   & 1 = Urbain ; 2 = Rural & 2 \\
    \cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Appeau & Type d'approvisionnement en eau & 1 = Eau potable ; 2 = Eau non conseillé & 2 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Instrumer & Niveau d'instruction de la mère & 1 = Aucun \par
    2 = Primaire \par
    3 = Sécondaire et plus & 3 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Ehtnie & Ethnie & 1 = Bamilike/Bamoun \par
    2 = Des regions cotier \par
    3 = Du grand nord \par
    4 = Etranger et autres & 4 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Religion & Réligion & 1 = Catholic
    2 = Protestant \par
    3 = Moslem \par
    4 = Other & 4 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{} \\% \bigstrut[t]\\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\ %\bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Les facteurs 
                    liés à }\end{sideways}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{ l'attitude la mère}\end{sideways}}} & Consulpre & Consultations prénatales & 1 = Aucune visite  \par
    2 = Moins de dix visites \par
    3 = dix visite et plus & 3 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Lieuaccou & Lieu d'accouchement & 1 = Dans un hôpital ou centre de santé 
    2 = A domicile & 2 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Vacci & N'a jamais été vacciner & 1 = Oui ; 2 = Non & 2 \\
    \cline{3-6}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Poidsnass & Poids à la naissance & 1 = [0-3[ ; \par 2 = [3-6[ ; \par 3 = [6-8[ ; \par 4 = NSP & 4 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

But at the end, I would like to obtain something of like this :

[image]

Thank you to help me !!

Comment: If you put the `\multirow` on the last line with a negative number-of-rows specification, it will probably work better. At least, that's what I've found in the past.

Comment: What do you mean by `leaning text`?

Comment: What's with the p{1pt}?

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution, with the `makecell` and `enumitem` packages. The former allows for linebreaks in cells and a common formatting, through the `\thead`, `makecell`, `rothead` and `\rotcell` commands.
With the latter, I defined a new enumerate-like environment, with parameters adapted for use in table cells, then a new column type, `E`, with cells inside this new list environment.

Finally, I changed some table formatting choices to suit my personal taste.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,caption,color}
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label={\arabic*${}={}$}, labelsep=0pt, wide=0pt, leftmargin=1.85em,nosep, itemsep=1pt}%
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\RaggedRight\tabenum\item[]}m{3.2cm}<{\endtabenum\vspace*{-2ex}}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellset{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont{Facteurs Socio-économiques}}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
  \sffamily\scriptsize
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{r| >{\ttfamily}l|l|E|c|}%p{15 pt}
    \cline{2-5}
    & \multirowthead{4}[4pt]{Variable} & \multirowthead{4}[4pt]{Description} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Modalité}} \\
    \cline{4-5} \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \thead{Unité ou codage} & \thead{Nbre} \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Sex & Sexe & \item Masculin \item Féminin & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Agemer & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Âge de la mère à la naissance } & \item Moins de 20 ans \item 20-34 ans \item 35 et plus & 3 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Gemeli & Gémellité & \item Singleton \item Jumeaux \item Triplés & 3 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multirow{-11}{*}[17ex]{\rotcell{Facteurs démographiques}}
                                                                  & Morta & Mortalité des enfants & \item Décédé av. 5 ans \item Vivant ap. 5ans & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Milresi & Milieu de résidence & \item Urbain \item Rural & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Appeau & Type d'approvisionnement en eau & \item Eau potable \item Eau non conseillée & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Instrumer & Niveau d'instruction de la mère & \item Aucun \item Primaire \item Secondaire et plus & 3 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Ethnie & Ethnie & \item Bamiléké/Bamoun \ \item Des régions côtières \item Du grand nord \item Étrangers et autres & 4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multirow{-15}{*}[9ex]{\rotcell{Facteurs socio-économiques}} & Religion & Religion & \item Catholique \item Protestant \item Musulman \item Autre & 4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ùùù%%%%%
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ùùù%%%%%
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Consulpre & Consultations prénatales & \item Aucune visite \item Moins de dix visites \item Dix visite et plus & 3 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Lieuaccou & Lieu d'accouchement & \item Dans un hôpital ou centre de santé \item À domicile & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
                                                                  & Vacci & N'a jamais été vacciné & \item Oui \item Non & 2 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multirow{-13}{*}[13ex]{\rotcell{ Facteurs liés \\à l'attitude de la mère}}
                                                                  & Poidsnass & Poids à la naissance & \item{} [0-3[ \item{} [3-6[ \item{} [6-8[ \item NSP & 4 \\
    \cline{2-5}
  \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you drop the rotated content completely and try something like this (based on Bernard's solution):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem,array,booktabs,caption}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label={\arabic*${}={}$},
  labelsep=0pt, wide=0pt, leftmargin=1.85em, nosep}
\newcolumntype{E}{%
  >{\RaggedRight\tabenum\item[]\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}%
  p{3.2cm}%
  <{\endtabenum\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering\sffamily\scriptsize
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily}llEc@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Facteurs démographiques} \\\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Variable} & Description & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Modalité} \\\cmidrule(l){3-4}
    && \multicolumn{1}{l}{Unité ou codage} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Nbre}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
    %%
    Sex  & Sexe & \item Masculin \item Féminin & 2 \\\addlinespace
    Agemer & Âge de la mère à la naissance 
    & \item Moins de 20 ans \item 20-34 ans \item 35 et plus & 3 \\\addlinespace
    Gemeli & Gémellité & \item Singleton \item Jumeaux \item Triplés & 3 \\\addlinespace
    Morta & Mortalité des enfants & \item Décédé av. 5 ans \item Vivant ap. 5ans & 2 \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
    %%
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Facteurs socio-économiques}\\\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-4}
    Milresi & Milieu de résidence & \item Urbain \item Rural & 2\\\addlinespace
    Appeau & Type d'approvisionnement en eau 
    & \item Eau potable \item Eau non conseillée & 2 \\\addlinespace
    Instrumer & Niveau d'instruction de la mère 
    & \item Aucun \item Primaire \item Secondaire et plus & 3 \\\addlinespace
    Ethnie & Ethnie & \item Bamiléké/Bamoun \item Des régions côtières 
    \item Du grand nord \item Étrangers et autres & 4 \\\addlinespace
    Religion & Religion 
    & \item Catholique \item Protestant \item Musulman \item Autre & 4 \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
    %%
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Facteurs liés à l'attitude de la mère} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-4}
    Consulpre & Consultations prénatales & \item Aucune visite 
    \item Moins de dix visites \item Dix visite et plus & 3 \\\addlinespace
    Lieuaccou & Lieu d'accouchement & \item Dans un hôpital 
    ou centre de santé \item À domicile & 2 \\\addlinespace
    Vacci & N'a jamais été vacciné & \item Oui \item Non & 2 \\\addlinespace
    Poidsnass & Poids à la naissance & \item{} [0-3[ \item{} [3-6[ 
    \item{} [6-8[ \item NSP & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok !! thanks you too for this second solution !! It's nice!